FluentResult: How to return Result.Fail for Result and Result<T> (generic and nongeneric)
I use FluentResult in C#.
For evaluation, I want to have a function like this:
public TRes Check<TRes>(TRes input) where TRes : ResultBase
{
    if(input.isFailed)
    {
        return Result.Fail("New Message");
    }
    return input;
}

I would like to have this handling of generic and non generic in other way too, so my problem is not only this special case of changing an error message.
Because FluentResult has no easy inheritance structure, I cant think of a way to do so.
I guess that it should be possible, because I know the right type and if I do this in two functions, it works fine, but if you know how I could do this in one function, I would like to hear your suggestions.

Looking a the documentation, there is a Result<T> class. So you can either return Result.Fail<TRes>("New Message"); or return Result.Ok(input);.

This is true but I would prefer to directly get the result, not a Result. I do not know in code, if TRes will be of Type Result or Result. But either one is not casteable to TRes when using Result.Fail(). I need smth (preferably not another method) that can handle both types and returns a respective fail result.

"I would prefer to directly get the result" -> but what if the method fails? There would be no direct result.

The method itself can fail with a specific reason, but should return a result or result depending on the input. It should never return a Result.
